# How to display loaded image to screen SDL2, completely stuck

Tags: c++, image, sdl-2

So I've been trying to get this to work forever and just can't. The image that `filename` refrences exists. I've done a bunch of googling and used GPT and as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything right. I've tried different ways from other tutorials and answers here but they didn't work either. Here's the g++ command, please help, what am I missing?

`g++ Main.cpp -orun -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lGL -I/usr/local/include/SDL2`

Edit: Using linux, Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS from system76

Edit 2: Moved code into main() b/c that's where it sits right now, oops

Edit 3: When I run the code, nothing happens. After I added `std::cout << "here\n";` in the while loop, it prints that out but visually nothing changes/pops up. No compile errors, no runtime errors

Edit 4: So I've now tested with the most basic SDL2 program I could find,

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    640,
    480,
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
  );
  if(window == NULL){
    printf("Fail: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }
  SDL_Delay(3000);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

compiling with the same command as mentioned above and no window ever pops up. No errors anywhere. So I'm thinking this is a system problem but I've confirmed that SDL2 is installed, I have headers and libs. From here I'm not sure where to go, google hasn't helped as I can't find anything that talks about this.

```
int main(){
// Initialize SDL
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
      std::cout << "Failed to initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      return 1;
  }
  // Initialize SDL_image
  int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
  if ((IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags) != imgFlags) {
      std::cout << "Failed to initialize SDL_image: " << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
      SDL_Quit();
      return 1;
  }
  SDL_Surface* image_surface = IMG_Load(filename);
  if (image_surface == nullptr) {
      std::cout << "Failed to load image: " << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
      IMG_Quit();
      SDL_Quit();
      return 1;
  } 
  // Create an SDL window
  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Image Viewer", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    image_surface->w, image_surface->h, 
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_KEYBOARD_GRABBED
  );
  if (window == nullptr) {
      std::cout << "Failed to create SDL window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);
      IMG_Quit();
      SDL_Quit();
      return 1;
  }

  // Create a renderer
  SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  if (renderer == nullptr) {
      std::cout << "Failed to create SDL renderer: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
      SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);
      IMG_Quit();
      SDL_Quit();
      return 1;
  }
  // Create a texture from the surface
  SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image_surface);
  if (texture == nullptr) {
      std::cout << "Failed to create SDL texture: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
      SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
      SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);
      IMG_Quit();
      SDL_Quit();
      return 1;
  }
  // Wait for a key press to exit
  bool quit = false;
  SDL_Event event;
  // SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
  while (!quit) {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);                          // Clear the renderer
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);// Copy the texture to the renderer
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);                        // Update the renderer
    // SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        quit = true;
      }
    }
    std::cout << "here\n";
  }
  // Cleanup
  SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);
  IMG_Quit();
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code loads and displays the image I supply correctly. What image format is it? Is the image file corrupt?

Comment: So then would something be wrong with my system? I tried running the example from https://gist.github.com/armornick/3434362 and that didn't work either

Comment: It's a PNG file and I don't think it's corrupt. I'm able to open it from the file explorer fine. I also just made another PNG using Krita and it didn't open that either

Comment: If you try to start an `xterm` from the command prompt, does it show up?

Comment: It doesn't, do I need that?

Comment: Your code is C++. Why have you tagged it with C and attract people that do  use C++? The tag [tag:C]: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question, nor add "solved" to the title. Instead, post and "answer" below with your findings.

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: Thanks. You should also press the checkmark next to your answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying everything I could I figured it must be a problem with my system or setup or something along those lines. What ended up working for me was building from source following the inctructions from https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Installation under the linux section. If anyone sees this and feels like explaining why I needed to do that and using `sudo apt-get install lib-name` didn't work that would be greatly appreciated.